# Find column with specific value, then get average of cells below

Tags: google-sheets

My Google Sheets has sheets that look something like this

Sheet1:

|  | Date | Object 1 | Object 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group A | Any Date | 1 | 3 |
| Group B | Any Date | 2 | 4 |

Sheet2:

|  | Date | Object 2 | Object 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | a | b |
| Group C | Any Date | 5 | 6 |

Now what I want is a formula for any a and b, that checks which object it belongs to, and gets all values, in the last 6 months, in the column of that object across all specified sheets, obviously without including itself.
In this case, a would be the average of 5, 3 and 4, so 4. Because 5 is in the same column as a, and 3 & 4 are in the column with object 2, which is the object a is in.
Basically because a is in the object 2 column, I want the average of all values of object 2.

In the case of b however, 6 should be the result because there is no object 5 in the other sheet (it may be in other sheets though) and therefore it takes the average of just 6.

Sheet1 does not care what is in Sheet2, there is at least one other Sheet, aside from Sheet1, that Sheet2 will get its values from.

Currently Im doing it manually, but for any change I have to check all sheets for cells that that would be affected. That would take too much time in the future though, as the amount of data will increase.
The formula for now looks like this:

```
=(SUMIF($D6:$D;">=" & edate(today();-6); S6:S) + SUMIF('Sheet1'!$D6:$D;">=" & edate(today();-6); 'Sheet1'!S6:S))/(COUNTIF($D6:$D;">=" & edate(today();-6)) + (COUNTIF('Sheet1'!$D6:$D;">=" & edate(today();-6))))
```

In my sheets column D has the Dates, and starting with Column S comes the Data. a and b are all in the first 5 rows, so they are never included.

This can probably be done with a Query or Arrayformula, but Im not good enough with those. I was at most able to recreate the edate portion of the formula.

Comment: Can you provide your expected output as a sample table? Also it seems unclear to me how  `A would be the average of 5, 3 and 4` has become, can you clarify more on that logic as well?

Comment: Not sure what I can add to what I have already said, but basically, all variables are the average for the corresponding object. "a" is the average of all values of "Object 2", meaning I want to calculate the average of all values in columns that contain "Object 2". Object 2 has the values 3 and 4 (in Sheet1) and 5 (in Sheet2).
Also, the expected outputs for a and b are: a = 4 and b = 6